# Debugging TS file in VS code opens the compiled file

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger, aws-serverless

I work with VS Code on a serverless node project in typescript.

until a couple of days, the debug works just fine - the breakpoint stops in the place that I added it and everything was good.

before a couple of days (probably by some version changing of my OS mac or in VS code) the debugger behavior starts to be strange.

i add a breakpoint on a TS file:

[image]

but it will open it in the end if the  COMPILED file :(

[image]
[image]
[image]

another sign that something is changed is that I can see a lot of "child process helpers" in the call stack:

[image]

and before i just saw the TS files and functions that were calling to the function that the breakpoint is(as i  expected).

my ts config looks like this:

```
    {
     "compilerOptions": {
     "lib": ["es2019"],
     "removeComments": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "noUnusedLocals": true,
     "noUnusedParameters": false,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "target": "es2017",
     "outDir": "lib",
     "inlineSources": true,
     "resolveJsonModule": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "sourceRoot": "/",
     "baseUrl": "./",
     "paths": {
       "@src/*": ["src/*"],
       "@tests/*": ["tests/*"],
       "@models/*": ["models/*"],
       "@managers/*": ["managers/*"],
       "@constants/*": ["constants/*"],
       "@api-types/*": ["api-types/*"]
     }
   },
   "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules/**/*",
     ".serverless/**/*",
     ".webpack/**/*",
     "_warmup/**/*",
     ".vscode/**/*"
   ]
 }
```

and my settings for this debug looks like this:

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "local",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless",
        "args": [
          "offline",
          "--noTimeout",
          "--stage=dev",
          "--region=us-east-1",
          "--clustername=us1"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "runtimeArgs": ["--lazy"],
        "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/.webpack/**/*.js"],
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "runtimeExecutable": "node",
        "env": {},
        "windows": {
          "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\serverless\\bin\\serverless"
        },
        "outputCapture": "std"
      },
    ]
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like REMOVING this line:

```
"outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/.webpack/**/*.js"],
```

from `launch.json` fix this issue...

Comment: can't thank you enough man! I tried to make this work all day